# SQL Query too add up how many times a unique string occurs

Tags: sql, addition

For example if I was creating a Pizza shop database it would look like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQGUY.png]

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT pizza_type, COUNT(*) as 'NumberOrdered'
FROM table
GROUP BY pizza_type
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the COUNT() function and GROUP BY

```
select pizza_type, count(*) as NumberOrdered
from orders
group by pizza_type
```